# How to group related traffic signals

Tags: openstreetmap

I am working on a project involving roads and traffic signs. I can retrieve Tag:highway=traffic_signals data which maps to individual signals present on roads.

How can I group related traffic signals which are operated in coordination with each other?

Comment: hm that's quite a leap, from having traffic signal positions to their wiring logic; there might be an inherent spatial dependency to the wiring, a topology, but I guess you'd need to provide data to fill that gap.

Comment: Well, it does not have to contain all the signals that run through the same wiring logic. If I can only map all the signals of a junction together, I think it would be enough.

Comment: in theory, OSM data should have a *node* at every intersection, referred to by every edge that either starts or ends in it. this includes roads crossed by footpaths etc., and with a bit of logic you could try and assign the id of the closest *node* that represents an intersection of two or more *ways* to each signal and then group by that id. in practice, however, you might encounter a bunch of inconsistencies with this approach I guess. it is still a good first approach I'd say; maybe search GIS.SE for *PostGIS KNN* queries and see how far you get.

Comment: ...if PostgreSQL/PostGIS is something you are willing/able to work with.

Comment: I am already working on what you have suggested but following this approach, a question arises that what should be a good distance to group signals together. Inside the city traffic signals could be very tightly located while on country road crossings signals can be further away while still synced to each other. Looks like there is no data structure available inside OSM that can do this automatically.

Comment: the key here would be to find **the closest *node* to each signal**, i.e. running a *Nearest Neighbor* search **for each signal**. if I'm correct, you are implying a proximity search for each *node*, which would be quite the opposite approach (and bound to fail, I dare say).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing a close proximity search to include all related signals in an area (based on nodes as I am already working with them). I am still not sure how this approach is different than yours? You are suggesting that I pick up a traffic signal node and find its neighboring nodes until I can mark them all as one, ideally, they should be located at the same distance from each other. Isn't this the same approach?

Comment: I suggest to pick a signal *node* and find the **one closest intersection *node* to it**. and repeat with all signals. could you add what software you are using, as it is crucial to a possible answer?

Comment: Are you still working on this? Have you further developments? Picking in the previous comments, if you are trying to set a adaptable search threshold for your nearest neighbor analysis that takes in count if it is dealing with a local road or a major road, you could try to use the road hierarquy attributes of the OSM data

Comment: No, It was a university assignment, I tried both approaches and none worked. After discussing it with my teacher, we decided to move in another direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openstreetmap data does not usually include anything linking separate traffic signals, indicating that they belong in practice as one coordinated set. Some discussion of the issue can be found on the Openstreetmap documentation (itself a collaborative wiki) here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dtraffic_signals#Complex_intersections

The conventions used in Openstreetmap mapping are themselves an emerging set of conventions, rather than a set of absolute rules. This means that there may be local variation in how signals are mapped.

Therefore, your only options are to apply some logic to group signals. A familiarity with local conventions used to map the signals would help a great deal. You may need to infer links by proximity, and by connection (by OSM ways).